# d3.js group by time period

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can i nest data by same sized timespans like decades.

## From this

```
 [{key: "1432"}
 {key: "1436"}
 {key: "1557"}
 {key: "1559"}
 {key: "1834"}
 {key: "1836"}
 {key: "1839"}
 {key: "undefined"}]
```

## To this

```
[{key: "1430-1439", values: Array}
{key: "1550-1559", values: Array}
{key: "1830-1839", values: Array}
{key: "undefined", values: Array}]
```

Additionally it would be nice if the size of the timespan is calculated dynamically.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also, you need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Comment: Thavit, take a look at d3's [histogram generator](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450), which will help to divide an array into bins.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by looping over all of the elements and add the corresponding decade to it like here.

```
for(i = 0; i < dataToDraw.length; i++) {
  if(dataToDraw[i].year != undefined) {
    var decadeStart = dataToDraw[i].year - dataToDraw[i].year % 10;
    dataToDraw[i].decade = decadeStart + "-" + (decadeStart + 9);
  }
}
```

After that I used d3.nest to nest the data by the new decade field.

```
nestedDecadeData = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) { return d.decade; })
.sortKeys(d3.ascending)
.entries(dataToDraw);
```